# How do I figure out the longitude and latitude coordinates necessary to create a circular 1 mile radius around one location?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, geometry, algebraic-geometry, differential-geometry

How do I figure out the longitude and latitude coordinates necessary to create a circular 1 mile radius around one location? I don't mind how many coordinates that takes.

For instance: Latitude = 28.4789 Longitude = -81.4682

What mathematical **theorem** or **formulas** would you use to accomplish a task like this?

Comment: See http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/14902/21483.

Answer (score 0):

You can consider first a great circle containing, say, the latitude (I assume latitude goes from north-to-south). Then (assuming the Earth is a perfect sphere ), consider the representation $$x^2+y^2+z^2=r^2 $$ of the sphere/earth, where $r$ is the radius of the Earth. All arcs along a great circle have proportional length . Now, for the longitude,you can translate your point from spherical coordinates to Euclidean, to get a point $(x_0,y_0,z_0)$ . Intersect the plane $z=z_0$ with the sphere in the above equation to get a horizontal circle $x^2+y^2=r^2-z_0^2$. In this circle, set up the equation for arc-length of a circle, and set this arclength equal to 1.

Comment: I'm sure I'm missing something, but I can't see how the above example inputs a singular longitude and latitude as mentioned and then outputs the relative longitude and latitude coordinates to form a 2 mile radius around the original location.

Comment: @Tyrer: Maybe it's my explanation that is missing; please give me some time to rewrite.